# How to add a field or any text to onepage step from layout file

Tags: layout, onepage-checkout, frontend

I'm trying to add a block to the shipment step without touch the shipping_method.phtml file.

On my layout file if I use content as reference I can show my file but I can't find the way to show my file inside the step.

This works:

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name='content'>
        <block type="core/template" name="my_name_module_file" as="my_name_module_file" after="checkout.onepage.billing" template="module/text_shipment.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

I'm trying this:

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name='checkout.onepage.shipping_method'>
        <block type="core/template" name="my_name_module_file" as="my_name_module_file" template="module/text_shipment.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, nevermind, I got it.

Seen this: [Adding custom fields to review form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4478/adding-custom-fields-to-review-form)

And checking `layout/checkout.xml` to check the correct reference.

```
<checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>

        <block type="core/template" name="my_module_file" as="my_module_file" output="toHtml" template="module/text_shipment.phtml" />

</checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as solution!